# How to put a text on the side of a image?

Tags: css, css-float, overflow

I have this code below:

```css
.img-container{
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
    
.img-container img{
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1.2s ease;
  transition: transform 1.2s ease;
 }
    
 .img-container:hover img{
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
```

```html
<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-8">
      <div class="mb-3 mb-md-0">
    
        <div class="img-container">
          <a href="index.php?post=#"><img  style="float: right; width: 400px" src="https://www.revistaplaneta.com.br/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2017/05/5_pl530_volta8.jpg" alt="#" class="card-img-top"></a>
        </div>
    
        <div class="card-body">
          <h3 class="cardTitleID"><a href="index.php?post=#" class="card-title">title</a></h3>
          <p class="card-text text-muted">text</p>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
```

I need to float the `<img>` on the right, but the `overflow: hidden;` on the `css` is not letting me do it...

How can i solve this??.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this but I personally prefer the flex approach:

```css
div.mb-3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.img-container{
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
    
.img-container img{
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1.2s ease;
  transition: transform 1.2s ease;
 }
    
 .img-container:hover img{
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
```

```html
<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-8">
      <div class="mb-3 mb-md-0">
    
        <div class="img-container">
          <a href="index.php?post=#"><img  style="float: right; width: 400px" src="https://www.revistaplaneta.com.br/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2017/05/5_pl530_volta8.jpg" alt="#" class="card-img-top"></a>
        </div>
    
        <div class="card-body">
          <h3 class="cardTitleID"><a href="index.php?post=#" class="card-title">title</a></h3>
          <p class="card-text text-muted">text</p>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The beauty of it is that its super simple, its almost fully supported across browsers now, and you automatically gain pixel perfect horizontal and vertical alignment :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `.img-container` is a DIV that will expand to be 100% width if you don't tell it otherwise. Add  `float: right` and it will only take up the width of the image it wraps.

```css
.img-container{
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 4px;
  float:right;
}
    
.img-container img{
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1.2s ease;
  transition: transform 1.2s ease;
 }
    
 .img-container:hover img{
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
```

```html
<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-8">
      <div class="mb-3 mb-md-0">
    
        <div class="img-container">
          <a href="index.php?post=#"><img  style="float: right; width: 400px" src="https://www.revistaplaneta.com.br/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2017/05/5_pl530_volta8.jpg" alt="#" class="card-img-top"></a>
        </div>
    
        <div class="card-body">
          <h3 class="cardTitleID"><a href="index.php?post=#" class="card-title">title</a></h3>
          <p class="card-text text-muted">text</p>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead making your `<img>` float, just declare `style="display:inline-block;"` on your divs which has classes "img-container" and "card-body"